# Sencha Touch2: Passing data from Controller to floating Panel not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2, panel

I am new to Sencha Touch2 and facing problem while passing data from my Controller to Floating panel on listitem tap. Here is my controller implementation code:

```
Ext.define('CustomList.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires:['CustomList.view.DatePanel'],

    config: {
        refs: {
            listView: 'listitems'
        },

        control: {
            'main test2 list': {
                activate: 'onActivate',
                itemtap: 'onItemTap'
            }
        }
    },

    onActivate: function() {
        console.log('Main container is active');
    },

    onItemTap: function(view, index, target, record, event) {
        console.log('Item was tapped on the Data View');
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'DatePanel'
        });
     }

});
```

Am able to get data in the controller and DatePanel.js is my floating Panel.
DatePanel.js:

```
Ext.define('CustomList.view.DatePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.DatePanel',
    xtype:'datepanel',
    config: {
        itemid:'DatePanel',
        modal:true,
        centered: true,
        hideOnMaskTap:true,
        width:'500px',
        height:'650px',
        items:[
            {
                styleHtmlCls:'homepage',
                tpl:'<h4>{name3}</h4>'

            },
            {
                xtype:'toolbar',
                docked:'bottom',
                items:[{
                    text:'OK',
                    ui:'confirm',
                    action:'ShowTurnOverReport',
                    listeners : {
                        tap : function() {
                            console.log('Ok');
                        }
                    }
                },
                    {
                        text:'Cancel',
                        ui:'confirm',
                        action:'Cancel',
                        listeners : {
                            tap : function() {
                            console.log('Cancel');
                            var panelToDestroy = Ext.getCmp('datepanel');
                            panelToDestroy.destroy();
                            Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('CustomList.view.Test2'));//Test.js is my list Panel

                            }
                        }
                    }]

            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Help me out in destroying the panel on 'Cancel' Button.
Can anyone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: use id value 'DatePanel' in getCmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create instance of panel you want to add first.

```
var floatingDatePanel = Ext.create('Yourapp.view.YourDatePanel');
```

Next get data of selected list item on itemTap

```
var data = record.getData();
```

Assign this data to `floatingDatePanel` with `setData()` method

**UPDATE**,

after looking at your panel code, I guess you want to set data to first item in panel ie

```
        {
            styleHtmlCls:'homepage',
            tpl:'<h4>{name3}</h4>'

        }
```

Right ? If so then you need to change following code

```
floatingDatePanel.setData(data);
```

to

```
floatingDatePanel.getAt(0).setData(data);
```

Because, it is first item inside panel that is having a template assigned and hopefully the same where you want to set data.

then finally, you can add this panel into viewport with

```
Ext.Viewport.add(floatingDatePanel);
```

Comment: Thanks. But am not able to get data in my DatePanel.js.

Comment: added DatePanel.js for your Reference.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It'll be clear if you state what you want to with data next. You just want to display it or operate on it later ? Also post the code for model and store used to display list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. its working now and can you please help me out on destroying the floating panel on 'Cancel' button click.

Comment: try `var panelToDestroy = Ext.getCmp('datepanel');` and then `panelToDestory.destroy();` but first, you need to add another item into  viewport that will take current panels place. And then destroy current panel. It'll be much easier if you could just use http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/navigation_view as parent to both list and datepanel.

Comment: I have used the above code to destroy panel.
am getting this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined'. and updated the DatePanel.js file. Thanks.